# PTRACE_TRACEME error "Operation not permmited"

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to use PTRACE_TRACEME to trace the child process:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/user.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t child_pid;
    int status;
    struct user_regs_struct regs;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s program [arguments]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid == 0) {
        /* Child process */
        
        /* Allow parent to trace this process */
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
            perror("ptrace3");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Replace child process with specified program */
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);

        /* If execvp returns, there was an error */
        perror("execvp");
        exit(1);
    } 
    else if (child_pid > 0) {
        /* Parent process */

        /* Attach to child process */
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, child_pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
            perror("ptrace5");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Wait for child process to start */
        waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);

        /* Continue running child process */
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child_pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
            perror("ptrace4");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Wait for child process to stop */
        waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);

        /* Do something with registers */

        /* Detach from child process */
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, child_pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
            perror("ptrace");
            exit(1);
        }
    } else {
        /* Fork failed */
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And I got the error on PTRCAE_TRACEME:

```
ptrace3: Operation not permitted
```

if I switch between the if condition of `PTRACE_ATTACH` to `waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);` at parent process:

```
/* Wait for child process to start */
waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);

/* Attach to child process */
if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, child_pid, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
     perror("ptrace5");
     exit(1);
}
```

I got the error on PTRACE_ATTACH:

```
ptrace5: Operation not permitted
```

As I understood it's related to security features, I tried to change the ptrace_scope to 0 and checked that SELinux is disable.
Also, I am not using in Docker and my disto is Ubuntu 22.04.
Thanks for your helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While security settings indeed can cause problems, in your code you are trying to trace it twice.

If you open `man 2 ptrace`, you will see in `EPERM` description

> Alternatively,  the process may already be being traced

What happens is:

1. If `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...)` is called first, then `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...)` failes because child process is already traced.
2. If `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...)` is called first, then `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...)` is failes for same reason.

Try replacing `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...)` with `waitpid(...)`

Comment: In addition to replacing `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH,...)` with `waitpid`, you also have to follow the `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME,...)` with a `raise(SIGSTOP)` or something like that, so that the parent has a chance to begin its tracing before the `execve`.  Otherwise the `waitpid` won't return until the child process has exited, which is far too late.

Comment: Oh, only now noticed your comment from 11 April. You know, you could answer your own question and mark it as real answer.

Comment: Nate, you are absolutely right.

Comment: Yes, I solved this issue.
But now I am stuck with finding the breakpoint address.
I have used with 'objdump' command and the breakpoint in the address I got.
It's not working, so I think maybe it's because of the ASLR or maybe because I am using the 64-bit machine.
What can cause not to find the breakpoint address by using objdump?

Comment: Are you trying to place breakpoint in some function? You can do it by executing `b functionname` in gdb console

Comment: I am not sure what you mean to set a place breakpoint in some function, how does it help?
for example, with gdb I did:
`b main`
and got:
**Breakpoint 1 at 0x13a5**
then I did also after I run:
`info address main`
and got:
**The symbol "main" is a function at address 0x555555555389.**
I 4 ways, but no one returns me SIGTRAP, but maybe the problem is not in the address.
`So, which address from these 4 is correct? or no one?`

**(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void *)regs.rip + 0x555555555389, 0)**

**(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void *)0x555555555389, 0)**

Comment: I add the two ways:
**(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void *)regs.rip + 0x13a5, 0)**
**(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, (void *)0x13a5, 0)**

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the linux security system.
This can be solved:

**1.** Run via sudo.

**2.** Сhange the OS kernel configuration to allow debugging processes. To do this, you can change the value of the /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope parameter.

**3.** Use another debugging function such as PTRACE_SEIZE, which can be more secure and does not require root privileges.

Comment: The solution was to remove the ATTACH and DETACH.
Now I got the error from the code waitpid:

wait: Success
after the CONT.
But I expected to get: Child got a signal: Trace/breakpoint trap.
It means that the address to set a breakpoint is invalid?
The full code: https://pastebin.com/ufHbnPQK